# Не срабатывает radio button

Tags: html, css

Вот верстка

```
<div class="pill_checlbox_2">
    <input type="radio" name="pill_checkboxes" id="pill_ch_3" checked />
    <label for="pill_ch_3">Аренда</label>
</div>
```

Вот CSS

```
.pill_checlbox_2 label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 21px 9px 21px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #cdcece;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000000;
}

.pill_checlbox_2 input:checked + label {
    border: 1px solid #3eb060;
    background-color: #3eb060;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

В input есть атрибут ckecked, то есть label должен становиться с зеленым фоном и белым шрифтом при загрузке страницы, но он таким не становится. Не знаю почему не работает. Как это решить?

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал в Google Chrome - работает. Наверное, ту проблема в браузере.
Что у меня:

[image]

Comment: Поправил вопрос. Прочтите заново пожалуйста.